# How do I set the HttpOnly flag of a cookie with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, httponly

I'm trying to create a cookie, with the HttpOnly flag enabled.

While there seems to be a plethora of resources about how to do it in Java and .Net, I need to do it in javascript.

Here is my (currently failing) function

```
createCookie = function(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; domain=my.domain.com; path=/; HttpOnly;";
```

Thanks -

Comment: Isn't the whole point of HttpOnly to prevent Javascript from accessing it? I would question the use case.

Comment: As far as I know, HTTP-only cookies cannot be accessed/created by JavaScript. That is the point, right?

Comment: Wouldn't setting a `httponly` flag by JavaScript defeat the purpose?

Comment: 3 comments saying the same thing :) cool we all think the same way!

Comment: I would have thought you could have created one, just not read it?

Comment: Just a small nuance: `HttpOnly` cookies can not be set *from the browser*, but it's perfectly possible from JS running *on the server*... in a Node JS based Express app for example.

Comment: @Steven Set =\= Access. In any case, the question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript

Answer (score 26):

You cannot access an HttpOnly cookie in JavaScript.

The following quotation is borrowed from [the Wikipedia material](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie):

> The HttpOnly cookie is supported by most modern browsers. On a supported browser, an HttpOnly session cookie will be used only when transmitting HTTP (or HTTPS) requests, thus **restricting access from other, non-HTTP APIs (such as JavaScript)**.

In other words, HttpOnly cookies are made to be used only on the server side.

I wrote an example in PHP:

```
<?php
$name = 'foo';
$value = 'bar';
$expirationTime = 0;    // Session cookie.
$path = '/';
$domain = 'localhost';
$isSecure = false;
$isHttpOnly = false;
setcookie($name, $value, $expirationTime, $path, $domain, $isSecure, $isHttpOnly);
?>
<script>
alert(document.cookie);
</script>
```

It alerts `foo=bar`.

Remove the cookie, change `$isHttpOnly` to `true`, reload the page, and you'll see an empty alert. But at the same time the browser stores the cookie to send it during a request to the server.