# Set HttpOnly attribute of a cookie as "True" using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, cookie-httponly

I have a function in Javascript which sets a cookie like this:

```
document.cookie = "name='Name'" + ";EXPIRES=sometime" + ";PATH=$PATH" + ";DOMAIN=domain" + ";SECURE=''";
```

I want to set the **HttpOnly** attribute of the cookie as **TRUE**.

How do I do that in Javascript?

I tried the following way which didn't work out:

```
document.cookie.HttpOnly = true;
```

Also, searched in *Google* but did not find any solution in Javascript.

Comment: Second link in google : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript .

Comment: Already had a look in this, didn't serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, this is impossible to do. You want set a attribute that isn't avaiable for scripting languages(JavaScript is a scripting language), with javascript.

From another question:

> A HttpOnly cookie means that it's not available to scripting languages
>   like JavaScript. So there's in JavaScript absolutely no API available
>   to get/set the HttpOnly attribute of the cookie, as that would
>   otherwise defeat the meaning of HttpOnly.

Source: [Set a cookie to HttpOnly via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript)

If you insist on doing this with JavaScript, I'm afraid you're at a dead end.