# Is it possible to read HTTPONLY cookies with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cookies

Is there any way of reading cookies marked with HTTPONLY checked, with jQuery? I have a cookie named `wishlist_cookie`.

When I try

```
$.cookie('wishlist_cookie');
```

It returns `NULL` even if it has a value.

Comment: Does the domain and path of the cookie match those you're trying to access it from? Have you included the cookie plugin correctly?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes it matches and the cookie plugin is being used at several other places on the website, just ran into a problem on this specific cookie and watched it and found out httponly was the problem :)

Answer (score 7):

HttpOnly cookie is not available to client-side scripting languages, there is no way to get and set it. Here is the link [Set a cookie to HttpOnly via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript) for details.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Glad helping you.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:** No.

**Explanation:** jQuery is nothing but an extended library of javascript. The HttpOnly flag tells if the cookie can be accessed/altered by the client side scripts which is a defensive mechanism for Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks. If by any chance the application is vulnerable to XSS injections, the attacker will not be able to get some critical cookie values like session ids.

Answer (score -2):

You can try in this way

```
var currentSession = [];


      var session = function readCookie() {
            match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('TestCookie' + '=([^;]+)'));
            if (match) {
                var array = match[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    name = array[i].split('=')[0];
                    value = array[i].split('=')[1];
                    currentSession.push(setCokiesValue(name, value));
                }
            }
            return currentSession;

        };
```

Comment: How does this help in any way?

Comment: try this ** document.cookie.match(new RegExp('wishlist_cookie'));**

Comment: @virender returns null