# Can we read Laravel cookies in jQuery and vice versa?

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, laravel-5, jquery-cookie

I've working on project where lots information stored in Cookies.
We've using PHP Laravel 5.2 framework and jQuery library 1.9. Every thing working fine but when  trying to read a cookies with jQuery that created with Laravel PHP code its return nothing but when checked it in browser cookies and read with PHP Laravel its working fine

Laravel Code:

```
Cookie::queue('COOKIE_NAME', $value, $minutes); //Create a cookie
```

jQuery Code:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("COOKIE_NAME"); //Return nothing
```

Comment: So long as the cookies share the same domain and path, then yes. Check in the console to ensure that is the case.

Comment: Yes its on same domain

Comment: If it's on same domain, you should check `cookies path` https://scontent.fhan5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/19225207_10203399234818197_7884831810528461733_n.jpg?oh=9fcdde1c9e25c006012afcd6a6a1212c&oe=59CC4543

Comment: Cookies path is also same because i'm using on index page

Comment: `Cookie::queue` try this `Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever($name, $value));`

Answer (score 1):

After few minutes of tested, I found this [Is it possible to read HTTPONLY cookies with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066064/is-it-possible-to-read-httponly-cookies-with-jquery). It means you cannot read HttpOnly cookies, so you should `compact` cookies value to the view instead or made it available like so, but you will deal with security issues I guess.

```
Cookie::queue('COOKIE_NAME', 'MyValue', 60, null, null, false, false);
```

With this kind of setting, you can read your cookies with jquery cookies.

P/S: Cookies value will be encrypted with base64, so you need to decrypt it before using.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can either make `ajax` request to retrieve the cookies from your controller or you can create a meta tag as

```
<meta name="cookie" content="{{ cookie_function() }}" />
```

in your blade.php file. Then using jquery

```
var cookieValue = $('meta[name="cookie"]').attr('content');
```