# HttpOnly cookie - unable to set

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to make the client receive a page that will set the required cookies after authentication, and then go to another page after setting the cookies.

Client => Server: credentials

Server => Client:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.cookie="name=myName;path=/;secure;HttpOnly";
            document.cookie="token=abcdefg;path=/;secure;HttpOnly";
            window.location="https://localhost/myPage.html"
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This fails when `HttpOnly` is set. How do I fix it?

Comment: The reason to set http-only is to make sure script does not have access to the cookie

Comment: You need to set it via headers from the server side scripts that you are using... what is the server side technology used

Comment: It's called HttpOnly, not HttpAndJavaScriptOnly.

Comment: @Ja͢ck how about `HttpOnlyButWithJSThisOneTimeKthx`

Comment: Related: [Set a cookie to httponly via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

`HttpOnly` cannot be set (or read) from js - that's why it's called `HttpOnly`.

So answering your question:

> How do I fix it?

You cannot "fix" it - it's by design. But you could set it from the server side.