# How to set httpOnly flag in ngCookies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, jwt, httponly

I have a JWT token that I'd like to store in a cookie. The cookie needs to have at least HttpOnly flag set, but I would also want to set the Secure flag to true.

From the angular docs I know I can store my token in cookies like this:

```
// using 'ngCookies'

createToken(jwt_token) {
    $cookies.put('jwt', jwt_token);
},
retrieveToken() {
    return $cookies.get('jwt');
}
```

But it's not clear how I can specify the HttpOnly and Secure flags. [The docs say](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies#!) it has an options field for `put()` and `get()`, but [then it mentions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults) `$cookiesProvider`. I'm not sure how that fits in, or where it should be declared, or if it needs to be set every time I do a `put()` or `get()`?

So would it be something like:

```
createToken(jwt_token) {
    $cookiesProvider['domain'] = 'www.mydomain.com';
    $cookiesProvider['secure'] = true;
    $cookies.put('jwt', jwt_token);
},
retrieveToken() {
    $cookiesProvider['domain'] = 'www.mydomain.com';
    $cookiesProvider['secure'] = true;
    return $cookies.get('jwt');
}
```

Or is that completely wrong? I didn't see any HttpOnly flag either, but I do see `domain` which I set to `www.mydomain.com`. Is that equivalent to HttpOnly = true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a cookie to HttpOnly via Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this using ngCookies. A `HttpOnly` cookie can't be created from JavaScript, the alternative however, is to make an ajax query to the server that will add a `Set-Cookie` HTTP response.

Related: [Set a cookie to HttpOnly via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript)