# Angular: get cookie from one request and use in another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, cookies, couchdb

I have simple Angular app, which can perform some requests over `$http` to remote service (couchdb) at `example.com/.../myservice`. Service requires auth, which done by calling specified address `example.com/_session` with name and password and it returns with session cookie `AuthSession`. Problem is that cookie is not used when calls to service is done. Maybe problem caused because cookie is per-session Http-only (and that's can't be changed).

I think the solution is grabbing cookie from auth response, store and force it into service calls manually. But I don't know how to:

1. Get cookie from $http response
2. Force it with $http response

Any suggestions?

UPD: pics

All cookies

[image: all cookies]

but available only this

[image: only available cookie]

Auth cookie, which sent to `/_session` request, but not to others

[image]

Comment: Can you read the auth cookie from the authentication response? If so save it to the browser's local storage and then for each `$http` request use Angular to add to to the request header.

Comment: But how this can be done with Http-only cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no solution, according [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691716/570940)

Now I think that couchdb is a source of problem.
So, I'll try to find another ways to do auth in couch manually.