# I am getting Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am getting

> "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401"

while my other API like `GET`, `PUT`, and `POST` with `JWT` is working fine. I am wondering where could I go wrong? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again.

```
//JWT
function JWTAuthenticatToken(req, res, next) {

  const token = req.cookies.authcookie
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, userData) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(401).json({ error: "You have to be logged in!" })
    req.user = userData
    next()

  })
}

//client
const deletePost = async (id) => {
  const response = await Axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/delpost', { postId: id }, { withCredentials: true })
  const deleteData = dbdata.map(item => {
    if (item._id == response.data._id) {
      return response.data
    }
    else {
      return item
    }

  })
  setDBData(deleteData)

}
  
//express
router.delete('/delpost', JWTAuthenticatToken, async (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body)
  try {
    const post = await Post.findOne({ _id: request.body.postId }).populate("postedby", "_id")
    if (post.postedby._id === request.user.id) {
      post.remove({ _id: request.body.postId })
      return response.json({ message: "deleted succesfully" })

    }
  } catch (error) {
    return response.json({ message: error })
  }

})
```

Comment: You should add th token the headers in your  Axios.delete() call, where is your token ?

Comment: function JWTAuthenticatToken(req, res, next) {
 
    const token = req.cookies.authcookie
    jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET,(err,userData) =>{
     if(err) return res.sendStatus(401).json({error:"You have to be logged in!"})
        req.user = userData
        next()    
 
     }) 
 }

Comment: the JWT token is working fine for put post and get, but not delete

Comment: can you plase add that to your qustion ? it is very important part of your issue

Comment: Just add it to your delete in the headers of Axios.delete()

Comment: the code you pasted is from your axios

Comment: sorry, I don't get your question? I have added the JWT code in the question section.

Comment: you shouldn't send JWT via cookies, chech this answer please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176237/how-do-i-store-jwt-and-send-them-with-every-request-using-react/60875373

Comment: this code i have is working fine setting the withCredential:true. const response = await Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/comment',{text:text.index, postId:id}, {withCredentials:true})

Comment: cookies aren't secure since browser will send the autmaticaly

Comment: I have set the cookie to secure at the nodeJS.   const accessToken = jwt.sign({id:user._id}, process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET)
        res.cookie('authcookie',accessToken, {httpOnly:true})

Comment: does not mattr how you set it, your app should b able to controle 100% when the token is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Router.delete`. It'll work then.

Answer (score 0):

in the end, I found out that Axios does not support delete. I switch to post instead and it worked.