# React: Store JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt

I have a backend where the user gets a JSON Web Token if he is logged in successfully. This token is needed for other API calls and I want to store it application-wide to access it from every point in the application. What is the best point to store it and access it from anywhwere?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Storing JWT token in localstorage or session storage of a browser is not preferable, as it can be accessed easily by anyone who has even a little knowledge of browser developer options (especially developers like us).

I suggest you use http only cookie to store them, that way it can be accessed whenever you send a HTTP request.

You can read about it more - https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

You can store it on local storage on login like

```
export async function login(username, password) {
  const { data: jwt } = await http.post(apiEndpoint, { username, password });
  localStorage.setItem("token", jwt.token);
}
```

and than you can access it every time like

```
export function getCurrentUser() {
try {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("token");
    return jwtDecode(jwt);
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I have used widely this approach and works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest not to store in `localStorage`. I'd highly recommend  cookies.

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60875373/10427807).
In addition, also [See another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs).