# Syntax error when trying to fetch jwt key in Node.js and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I have been trying to get jwt token from REST API I implemented, but every time I try to do it accordingly to tutorials I found online I get an error. I have been searching for this problem 4 hours now but I was unable to find a solution. I read all other questions and tutorials like: [How do I store JWT and send them with every request using react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176237/how-do-i-store-jwt-and-send-them-with-every-request-using-react). Sadly every found foulution didn't work in my case. I would be grateful if you could at least tell me where can I learn to do it. I have been using REST API I created with Node.js Express in which there is method to generate JWT:

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthenticationToken = function () {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { _id: this._id, admin: this.admin, premium: this.premium },
    config.get(`jwtPrivateKey`)
  );
  return token;
};
```

I try to fetch data in React like this:

```
await fetch("http://localhost:1234/api/auth", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        localStorage.setItem("user-info", data.token);
      });
```

Here is error I receive:

```
   Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
```

And here is JWT key that was generated:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MGE2YTg4YzQzZDU2MzIwMjg1NWZlZjIiLCJhZG1pbiI6dHJ1ZSwicHJlbWl1bSI6dHJ1ZSwiaWF0IjoxNjIyMTMzMzAwfQ.CmQRtSaZc8g3TEF6R7flpJ9499QnfzlfgPNVazFaUsY
```

Comment: You sure it's sending JSON back? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: What's the exact response? It seems the error is because you're trying to parse it as JSON, but it's not in JSON format.

Comment: Here is what I get with console.log: Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:1234/api/auth", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning an object instead of a string from your express endpoint, for example:

```
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { _id: this._id, admin: this.admin, premium: this.premium },
    config.get(`jwtPrivateKey`)
  );
  return { token };
};
```