# document.cookie is not returning all the cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to read all the cookies set by my domain using `document.cookie` what I have noticed is, it returns only csrftoken and another value. My goal is to read the `sessionid` from the cookie

please see the below screenshot that shows the cookies set on my local machine
[image: Cookies on my local machine]

and this is the return value of `document.cookie`

[image: document.cookie console output]

[image: sessionid cookie value in Request Headers]

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript

Answer (score 11):

`_rbt_login_message` and `sessionid` are likely HTTP-only cookies, meaning they can be read only by the server when it's handling a page request, and not by any client-side JavaScript code.

This is usually done for session identifying cookies, since you (as a developer) don't want client-side code (which can be injected by a malicious third-party relatively easily) to be able to steal the session of one of your users.

Comment: How do I identify if they are HTTP-only cookies. In the HTTP response headers I only see `_rbt_login_message` in the `Set-Cookie` header.  Please see the following screenshot http://i.imgur.com/FzN68NJ.png