# Can't access cookie with HttpOnly flag from my React app using universal-cookie

Tags: reactjs, react-cookie

I'm setting up CSRF in my React application and I'm trying to access a cookie that has been set by my Node server.

I'm using `universal-cookie` to try to read the cookies. I can access some of the cookies, just not the one I need.

The cookies look like:

```
csrf_token_secret=s%3AXfLOSTp6QNLTeRk;
Path=/; Expires=Tue, 20 Mar 2018 12:34:34 GMT; HttpOnly

_csrf=PqswrVPP4GUePCh-0fFewrHh; Path=/
```

Using `universal-cookie` I tried:

```
 const cookies = new Cookies();

 console.log(cookies.get('csrf_token_secret')); 
 console.log(cookies.get('_csrf'));
```

I can access `_csrf` just fine but I can't get the value of `csrf_token_secret`.

What do I need to do differently to get the value of this cookie? I assume it has something to do with the `HttpOnly` flag?

Comment: Please make sure you're accessing the cookies from the same domain

Comment: booth cookies are created from my node app

Comment: Well, try this `cookies.set('myCat', 'Pacman', { path: '/' });
console.log(cookies.get('myCat'));` Do you see Pacman in your console?

Comment: yes the when i add myCat i see the correct results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HttpOnly tag means it can't be accessed by JS, only by your server.

this explains things in more detail...
[Set a cookie to HttpOnly via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript)