# Fix the issue of "Cookie Does Not Contain The HTTPOnly Attribute" on the client side

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, jquery-cookie

A recent security scan of my site indicates that the site has this issue:

```
Cookie Does Not Contain The "HTTPOnly" Attribute
```

I did research and found links about the fix. For example:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

However, all the links talk about doing some work on the server side through code or configuration. The way I do cookies on this site is adding/removing cookies via Javascript with the help of jquery-cookie found here

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

So, how can I fix this security issue?

**Updates**

Thank @cody for pointing me to another post. Basically, no client-side solution. Then another question:

Do I have to migrate my cookie-related Javascript code into server-side code (e.g., C# in my case)? I guess the answer is yes. I also guess that server-side configuration only (IIS in my case) won't work. Just wanted to check with experts here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a cookie to HttpOnly via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript)

Comment: Thank you! I updated my post.