# Cookie automatically becomes httpOnly

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

I have a web application deployed on WebSphere on a context root `/app`. Inside the application, there's a javascript which executes immediately after it's loaded, it looks something like this:

```
document.cookie = "foo=bar; path=/app";

setTimeout(function () {
    document.cookie = "baz=qux; path=/app";
}, 1000);
```

## Chrome behavior

From the DevTools I can see that initially `foo=bar` is created as ***non***-httpOnly and 1-2 seconds later it automatically becomes httpOnly. 
After waiting for 5 seconds or so (just to make sure), the second cookie is also created, but in non-httpOnly mode, the final result looks like this:

```
foo=bar (httpOnly=true)
baz=qux (httpOnly=false)
```

**Q1: Why foo=bar becomes httpOnly after some time?**

**Q2: How come that this delayed cookie creation makes such a difference?**

I can say that threshold is somewhere 700-800ms, if I delay cookie creation with less than this value, it behaves exactly as no delay at all.

## Firefox behavior

Here in case of delay lower than a threshold (or without any setTimeout)
it creates 2 cookies per kay,value pair, for example:

```
foo=bar; path=/app  (httpOnly=false)
foo=bar; path=/app/ (httpOnly=true)
baz=qux; path=/app  (httpOnly=false)
baz=qux; path=/app/ (httpOnly=true)
```

while in case of delay higher than a threshold, it does not create duplicate cookie (for baz=qux):

```
foo=bar; path=/app  (httpOnly=false)
foo=bar; path=/app/ (httpOnly=true)
baz=qux; path=/app  (httpOnly=false)
```

**Q3: Not to mention why FF appends slash at the end (I've heard different browsers handle cookies differently), why it's not the case for delayed cookie creation?**

I even thought that maybe there is a piece of script somewhere in the application which after some time "overwrites" non-httpOnly cookies to httpOnly one, but I don't think that's the case, because executing this from the console does not change anything:

```
document.cookie="baz=qux; path=/app; HttpOnly"
```

i.e. baz=qux remains as non-httpOnly. Some even claim that it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691716/1451174)

It's not a thing that server is resetting cookies to httpOnly via responses, I've checked each and every request in network view and these cookies are not coming from the server.

I have a gut feeling that there must be something in this environment because I tried to create a separate Spring boot project with a similar setup and all the cookies remain non-httpOnly.

Any ideas? Unfortunately, I can't share the real code. If someone's able to explain at least theoretically what could be the cause, that would be really helpful.

**Other notes:**

- This does not apply to cookies created with path=/
- Chrome version: 75.0.3770.100
- Firefox version: 67.0.4
- I'm using incognito window without any extensions

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a bit of further digging I think I've found the explanation

> It's not a thing that server is resetting cookies to httpOnly via
> responses, I've checked each and every request in network view and
> these cookies are not coming from the server.

That's not entirely true, apparently, WebSphere *was* sending back the cookie with httpOnly flag set, probably this was due to the [HTTPOnly flag](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/setting_the_secure_and_httponly_flags_on_the_jsessionid_cookie_in_websphere_application_server_v70_and_v8x?lang=en). However, it was not always visible in the Chrome/Firefox DevTools network view. I remember only one case (out of several tens) when this was visible. Not sure why browsers weren't showing it consistently (even with hard refresh)