# How to use key instead of `Set-Cookie` in Response Headers with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cookies, spring-security

I am having difficulty to store `cookies` in a React Native apps.

My goal is to send the `JSESSIONID` and `XSRF-TOKEN` as Response Header's keys instead of `Set-Cookie`, and the client will handle to store it as cookie manually.

1. I will store the `JSESSIONID` as cookie with `HttpOnly` set to true.
2. I will store the `XSRF-TOKEN` as cookie with `HttpOnly` set to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic Security Concepts:

- **1. Session Cookie (JSESSIONID for example).**

Should always be HttpOnly, have a domain set (or use the default as the server that provided it).
Never be stored anywhere other than the browser handling it. Your JS/HTML should know nothing about the JSESSION Cookie and only just move the user to a login screen if they get a 401 (UnAuthorised) from an endpoint.

- **2. CSRF Tokens.**

Back in the day (5 years a go probably ha!), most sites were rendered on the server. The server created the HTML and then just sent it back via the URI. Like you went to /profile then the server knew who you were and then created the profile page on its server and just fed back the HTML document.

When wanting to get some user input, this HTML rendered by the server would contain a `<form/>` which would collect user's data (password/bank details etc.) and then with the `onSubmit` passes it back to the server in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format

eg.
`https://thewebsite.com/sendmoney_to?account=512&amount=1milliondollars`

By simply sending that link to someone who has an active session with the site `thewebsite.com` the browser would visit it and carry out the request.

The victim is logged in as far as the site is concerned and will happily run that request sent by the attacker. These links were at one point even follower by simply loading an `<img>` like by posting on their wall or in an email etc.

So how did they fix this?

By adding some fields to the form called `hidden fields`. These hidden fields are created by the server when the page is rendered. They contain a  value that is the **CSRF TOKEN** and also something in a CSRF COOKIE. So when the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form is sent, it must have these values produced on the server when rendering the form. The server can then verify the form was the one they created and not some malicious link an attacker created.
An attacker can not know/guess these when making their naughty link.

- **3. Nower Days**

With having only JSON requests as many sites, like React Apps, are rendered client side and use Axios/Fetch...CSRF is somewhat redundant. You don't post forms/`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`...only make POST requests with a JSON body.

Sessions are still important as an XSS attack > CSRF attack. Store the session properly (JWT token or not...don't jump on the JWT band wagon  and start throwing that JWT Auth Token around Local Storage which seems to have become some kinda strange default for newer devs).

If you are sure you only have `application/json` capable endpoints, then the only way an attacker is going to get you to POST their content instead of what you are meant to is via an XSS attack. But once they have an XSS attack it is game over anyway. They are simply then you as far as the server is concerned as they use their naughty injected `<script>` to manipulate the request before it sent and the server would have no way of knowing it had been manipulated on the fly (usually).

- **4. Getting your CSRF Token via a Header as it wont be made in the form**

The XSRF-TOKEN you may need to expose the XSRF token by using a filter that will extract the CSRF Token (via the session) and adds it to a header on the response entity.

I wrote my own but it is basically the same in a library some use to do this same thing.

```java
@Log4j2
public class CsrfBindingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    protected static final String REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "_csrf";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME = "X-CSRF-HEADER";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME = "X-CSRF-PARAM";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, javax.servlet.FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
        log.debug("CRSF Token from session : {}", csrfToken != null ? csrfToken.getToken() : "CsrfToken is NULL");
        if (csrfToken != null) {
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME, csrfToken.getHeaderName());
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME, csrfToken.getParameterName());
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME, csrfToken.getToken());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

As far as the session, the browser should handle that and you should not be messing with it client side unless it is for a very specific reason (and I can't fathom one). The Cookies for Sessions are set as HttpOnly for the specific reason to disallow any JS running in the client to edit/read/add it.
One little cheeky advert/xss with some naughty code like `get the cookie called JSESSION ID if the host is myvictim.com and post it over here...` could mean you are compromised.

Read this for more detail:
[Add HttpOnly Cookie via JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript)
The browser should handle the `Set-Cookie` headers as intended and is best practice (out of security reasons and also just for plain simple ease of use).

**WebSocket STOMP Authentication**

Once a user has been authenticated via your `/login`, Spring should send a Set-Cookie header with the `JSESSIONID` Cookie. This cookie will be stored by the browser and should be inaccessible to your front end javascript app.

If you then use the STOMP Spring WebSocket implementation, you can get the principal user name from a STOMP message by getting it via the `StompHeaderAccessor` in the `@MessageMapping Controller` params.

`stompHeaderAccessor.getUser().getName()` would give the Spring Security authenticated user's principal name (usually their username or id, username is default).

```java
 @MessageMapping("/agents/start")
    public void start(StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor) {
        log.info("Subscriber Start! {}-{}", stompHeaderAccessor.getUser() != null ? stompHeaderAccessor.getUser().getName() : "ANON", stompHeaderAccessor.getSessionId());
        mysessionstore.addSessionId(stompHeaderAccessor.getSessionId());
    }
```

If you then want to edit the user's session attributes, you will then need to fetch their session id from the SPRING_SESSION table and you can use the Spring `SessionRepository` to fetch it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/SessionRepository.html

Comment: I see that you can't set Cookie with HttpOnly using JS. My current understanding is that XSS attack is possible if your server is compromised (e.g because of compromised CDN, or compromised library). So is it safe to store JSESSIONID and XSRF-TOKEN in LocalStorage?

Comment: No. Never for the session cookie.
XSS occurs say for example if you load advert or a user finds a way to add a comment to a post with script tags that can then run arbitrary JS.
For example, it could spread much like the original and first example of a Worm:
Samy Worm. 
Local storage is accessible by JS.
The ONLY place a JSESSIONID/SESSION token should live is in the Browser's HttpOnly Cookie store.
This also goes for authentication JWTs which you'll see many newbie devs (its the new fad) also store in local/session/ram.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the JSESSION cookie in a header not as a Set-Cookie header? What can you possibly do with it that would make any sense?
For example setting Axios to do `withCredentials=true` means the browser will send the JESSION  httponly cookie with every request (if the domains match on the cookie ofc). The use of HttpCookie and JSESSIONID means the the only thing you should care about on the front end javascript => get a 401 from an endpoint => Go to Login page. Your HTML/JS should know NOTHING about Session Cookies.

Comment: OK. Iv'e updated my answer with more details.
I'd look up more about XSS and CSRF attacks and how they are mitigated.
Also I'd look up / think about why storing JWT Auth tokens (and my god...they do it) including Refresh Tokens in Local Storage or sending them via headers isn't great...

Comment: I will answer your worry, I need JSESSIONID cookie in a header instead of a Set-Cookie for React Native apps authentication, I could not get the `Set-Cookie` when I use React Native Fetch API and the cookie behavior in React Native is different, it does not intercept HTTP request, so I need to refactor my Cookie-based authentication for the WebSocket handshake to http-header-based authentication.

To put into perspective, every WebSocket handshake (using stomp-js/stompjs library) in Browser will contain "Cookie: JSESSIONID=ABC123;" while in React Native apps it will not contain "Cookie"

Comment: I use STOMP for websockets. There should be no reason to be messing with the Set-Cookie headers. You definitely should NOT be changing the header `Set-Cookie` for the session cookie to allow your react app to store it / send it or whatever with it.
The browser automatically sends the session cookie with each STOMP message (you can get the user from the StompAccessorHeader on a STOMP controller...).

Comment: I will update my answer again showing how you normally get the session/principal user from a STOMP message...

Comment: I create a new SO's question about Spring WebSocket with `X-Auth-Token`. Please kindly check if you are interested, here's the [SO's question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930974/how-to-get-authentication-from-x-auth-token)

Comment: Thank you for the help, the WebSocket solution you provided is a great solution for `Cookie-based authentication`. My intention is to use `Cookie and CSRF` for the Browser while the Mobile Apps does not use Cookie.