# How to get Authentication from X-Auth-Token?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

My goal is to authenticate the WebSocket CONNECT frame. I wish to be able to initialize `Authentication user = ...` by using `X-Auth-Token`.

## TL:DR

I use the `X-Auth-Token` header. How the current authentication works:

1. User hit POST `/login` endpoint with Form Data `username` and `password`.
2. The response header will contain the key `X-Auth-Token`.
3. If you hit any REST endpoint with `X-Auth-Token` the server will recognize the user.
4. The issue is how to get Authentication from `X-Auth-Token` in the WebSocket CONNECT frame.

The current solution is to use JWT, however, one of the requirements for this project is a user should be able to invalidate the session. For JWT to be able to do that, the JWT should be a stateful, reference to this [SO's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405332/websocket-authentication-and-authorization-in-spring)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
// see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-stomp-authentication-token-based
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketAuthenticationConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
      @Override
      public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
          String sessionId = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("X-AUTH-TOKEN");
//          Authentication user; // How to get Authentication from X-Auth-Token?
//          accessor.setUser(user);
        }
        return message;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

What I did:

1. I change `Cookie-based authentication` by letting the session be provided in a header.

```
// see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-rest
@Configuration
// Override HttpSession's Filter, in this instance Spring Session is backed by Redis.
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

  // Default connection configuration, to localhost:6739.
  @Bean
  public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
  }

  // Tell Spring to use HTTP headers, X-Auth-Token.
  @Bean
  public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
    return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
  }
}
```

2. logic to CONNECT and SUBSCRIBE

```
const X-Auth-Token = "" // get from the POST `/login` endpoint

const onConnectCallback = () => {
  const destinations = ["/topic/channel/1", "/user/queue/messages"];
  for (let i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
    stompClient.subscribe(destinations[i], (payload) => {
      // receiveMessageCallback
    });
  }
};

const stompConfig = {
  brokerURL: "ws://localhost:8080/chat",
  connectHeaders: {
    "X-Auth-Token": X_Auth_Token,
  },
  onConnect: onConnectCallback,
};
const stompClient = new StompJs.Client(stompConfig);
stompClient.activate();
```

## Reference

I am worried that `X-Auth-Token` is not supported in WebSocket because based on [SO's answer there is no API to retrieve session by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499581/how-can-i-manually-load-a-java-session-using-a-jsessionid)

Comment: I'm not sure how much flex you have with your design, but this article details nicely why to avoid using JWTs as session tokens: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens It may inspire a different architecture that allows you to keep session management independent from authorization. (Apologies that this doesn't directly answer your question.)

Comment: @jzheaux I did not use JWT, I use the Spring Session. I use `X-Auth-Token` header instead of the `JSESSION` inside the `Cookie` header. The `X-Auth-Token` works out of the box for the REST endpoint, while it does not for the WebSocket endpoint.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, then by: "one of the requirements for this project is a user should be able to invalidate the session. For JWT to be able to do that," - what do you mean by "that" if not "maintain the session"?

Comment: @jzheaux By "that" I mean "maintain the session". But as per my knowledge, `JWT` supposedly to be stateless, therefore a user can't invalidate his token unless I store the invalidated token in a Redis, making it to be stateful. Not only, JWT require more bandwidth per HTTP handshake but it also need a Redis to be able to invalidate a token. While session do it out of the box, because everything is either stored in the spring app memory or in the redis.