# How can I create secure/httpOnly cookies with document.cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cookie-httponly

If I create the function:

```
function setCookie(name, value)
    {
      // this works:
      // document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/;";
      // this does not:
      // document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=strict";
    }
```

```
setCookie('my_cookie','some_random_value');
```

I am not 100% on why this second option is not working. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You can't create an HTTP-only cookie on the client. By definition it can only be created using HTTP from the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a cookie to HttpOnly via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies):

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it is sent only to the server. For example, cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript, and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

You can't set it with `document.cookie` because the *entire* point of the flag is to prevent it being set (or read) with `document.cookie`.

Comment: OK that makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: what about the developer tools/application/cookies, that should show the flag? it does have a column for it and it is showing the check for some of the cookies there but not for the one I am handling