# Cannot send httponly cookie using fetch

Tags: reactjs, cookies, httponly

I'm trying to send `HttpOnly` cookie from React frontend to NodeJS backend. I have checked that if the cookie is not `HttpOnly`, everything works as expected, but if not then the server does not receive any cookies.

```js
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

cookies.set(
  'refreshToken',
  'refreshToken',
  { 
    path: '/', 
    httpOnly: false, // this works
    // httpOnly: true, // this does not
    maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
  }
);

const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/refresh', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  credentials: 'include', // should enable sending HttpOnly cookie?
});
```

I tried setting domain as `localhost` but nothing changed. How should I fix this?

Comment: Clients cannot set `HttpOnly` cookies. "HttpOnly" is to be understood as "as opposed to JavaScript". Only the server can, via a `Set-Cookie` response header, set a `HttpOnly` cookie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a cookie to HttpOnly via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691654/set-a-cookie-to-httponly-via-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey very insightful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clients (i.e. some script in React) cannot set `HttpOnly` cookies. Only the server can, via a [`Set-Cookie` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), set a `HttpOnly` cookie. See [the relevant passage](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/#section-4.1.2.6-1) of the [IETF draft entitled *Cookies: HTTP State Management Mechanism*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis):

> The HttpOnly attribute limits the scope of the cookie to HTTP requests. In particular, the attribute instructs the user agent to omit the cookie when providing access to cookies via non-HTTP APIs.